# Symfony route not working with default and trailing /

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I'm beginning to work with Symfony 3. Testing routes, I created one with defaults as following:

```
index:
    path:     /test/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: MainBundle:Advert:index, name: maxime }
```

The route works with:

- /test/randomname
- /test

But not with

- /test/

Any idea why ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented here https://symfony.com/doc/master/routing/optional_placeholders.html

> Routes with optional parameters at the end will not match on requests
>   with a trailing slash (i.e. /blog/ will not match, /blog will match).

If you do need to match even `/test/` you can add the following route entry

```
index_trailing_slash:
    path:     /test/
    defaults: { _controller: MainBundle:Advert:index, name: maxime }
```

Comment: But then the parameter will not be variable

Comment: @Jeann yes it can, because you will have 2 routes, the first one with the variabile parameter and the second one with the fixed parameter. you can even remove the default value from the first

Comment: Ok ! it's a workaround then. Will remember it if needed.